# Javascript and COM intereaction

Tags: javascript, com

I am developing an application to communicate between javascript(front end) and COM Interface. Can someone tell me how to invoke the COM interface method in javascript ?.

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling a COM object from JavaScript will only work in ActiveX compatible browsers, namely Internet Explorer. Other browsers are unsupported, however there are third party extensions available, which may enable ActiveX awareness. Furthermore, your COM interface will need to need to be able to serve late bound clients, such as JavaScript in your case. This can be achieved by either declaring a `dispinterface` or implementing a dual interface via `IDispatch`.

From there, it's pretty straightforward to use a COM object:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test(){
                alert("Hello");
                var obj = new ActiveXObject("Math.MathCls");
                var res = obj.Add(3,4);
                alert("The answer is " + res);  
            }   
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="test()">Click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. however, i am still unable to view anything. Here is the code sample   :-                                                                    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function myfunction()
    {
       alert("i  am in in");
    var y = new ActiveXObject("SimpleATLcom.SimpleCom.1");
    var x = y.put_AtlMarks(20);
    alert(x);

Comment: if you have a sample program then please share the link .

Comment: Your code looks fine. Did you register your DLL? If in doubt, try to create an instance from another programming language, such as C#, and compare the results.

Comment: I validated it , it's registered properly but the only thing which is not working is when i am doing something like this :- var z = obj.somethod() and after this  i am just saying alert("called COM method") function but it doesn't popup any message . i am just guessing that it's unable to  recognize the method defined in the COM.

Comment: That's odd. Do you have a popup blocker installed? I suggest that you insert a Win32 `MessageBox` call into your method in order to check whether it actually succeeds. Also, make sure that your method name corresponds exactly to the one in your idl definition. I've edited my answer with a full html snippet.

Comment: I have tried the way you suggested and added the sample code too . Not sure what is going wrong over there.

Comment: The mistake what i did was incorrectly using the interface method. I really appreciate your help and response.

Comment: A small issue which was i am oberving though , whenever i call a get/set method it's not working correcting wherein if i call any independent function then it works fine. any pointers ?.

Comment: For instance :- get_COMMarks () and Put_ComMarks() , i am unable to see any message box being popped up . I tried calling GetCoMMarks() and SetCmMarks() but no luck.

Comment: Great to hear you got it working. Properties are accessed without their respective "get" and "put" prefix. For instance, if you have defined a property "Name" with "get_Name" and "put_Name" accessor, then you'll simply use "Name" in both read and write mode.

Comment: Another tip: Press F12 in Internet Explorer in order to bring up the developer tools. From there, you can debug your code and set breakpoints on calls to your COM object. The debugger can tell you why a call failed (such as due to a wrong property name).